# Struts2 insert html from string

Tags: html, struts2

Is it possible to pass a variable from a java file to a jsp by Struts, and this variable to contain html in itself ? (like "< p >hello < /p >"). Then I want to paste the content of this variable into the jsp file and it should create new html content. Can you give me a suggestion as I am beginner and I dont know how to work with that.. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is quite possible,you can send a simple String from your action class and can retrieve that in your JSP like

```
public class MyClass extends ActionSupport{

 private String myHTMLCode;
 //getter method
 //setter
  public String execute() throws Exception{
     myHTMLCode=// fill it with your HTML
  }

}
```

in JSP

```
<s:property value="myHTMLCode" escapeHtml="false"/>
```

Struts2 tags have property namely `escapeHtml` which tell underlying framework weather to escape HTML or not and for property tag its true by default

Comment: so, shouldn't the answer be '<s:property value="myHTMLCode" escapeHtml="false"/>' ?  +1 either way.

Comment: @rees:good catch..i explained it one way and showed example in wrong way,corrected